# Convert double differenced forecast into actual value diff() in R

Tags: r

I have already read

Time Series Forecast: Convert differenced forecast back to before difference level

and

How to "undifference" a time series variable

None of these unfortunately gives any clear answer how to convert forecast done in ARIMA using differenced method(diff()) to reach at stationary series.

code sample.

```
## read data and start from 1 jan 2014
dat<-read.csv("rev forecast 2014-23 dec 2015.csv")
val.ts <- ts(dat$Actual,start=c(2014,1,1),freq=365)

##Check how we can get stationary series
plot((diff(val.ts)))
plot(diff(diff(val.ts)))
plot(log(val.ts))
plot(log(diff(val.ts)))
plot(sqrt(val.ts))
plot(sqrt(diff(val.ts)))
##I found that double differencing. i.e.diff(diff(val.ts)) gives stationary series.

#I ran below code to get value of 3 parameters for ARIMA from auto.arima
ARIMAfit <- auto.arima(diff(diff(val.ts)), approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE, xreg=diff(diff(xreg)))
#Finally ran ARIMA
fit <- Arima(diff(diff(val.ts)),order=c(5,0,2),xreg = diff(diff(xreg)))

#plot original to see fit
plot(diff(diff(val.ts)),col="orange")
#plot fitted
lines(fitted(fit),col="blue")
```

This gives me a perfect fit time series. However, how do i reconvert fitted values into their original metric from the current form it is now in? i mean from double differencing into actual number? For log i know we can do 10^fitted(fit) for square root there is similar solution, however what to do for differencing, that too double differencing?

Any help on this please in R? After days of rigorous exercise, i am stuck at this point.

i ran test to check if differencing has any impact on model fit of auto.arima function and found that it does. so auto.arima can't handle non stationary series and it requires some effort on part of analyst to convert the series to stationary.

Firstly, auto.arima without any differencing. Orange color is actual value, blue is fitted.

```
ARIMAfit <- auto.arima(val.ts, approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE, xreg=xreg)
plot(val.ts,col="orange")
lines(fitted(ARIMAfit),col="blue")
```

secondly, i tried differencing

```
ARIMAfit <- auto.arima(diff(val.ts), approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE, xreg=diff(xreg))
plot(diff(val.ts),col="orange")
lines(fitted(ARIMAfit),col="blue")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIDt2.png)

thirdly, i did differencing 2 times.

```
ARIMAfit <- auto.arima(diff(diff(val.ts)), approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE, 
xreg=diff(diff(xreg)))
plot(diff(diff(val.ts)),col="orange")
lines(fitted(ARIMAfit),col="blue")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckIor.png)

A visual inspection can suggest that 3rd graph is more accurate out of all. This i am aware of. The challenge is how to reconvert this fitted value which is in the form of double differenced form into the actual metric!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect that differencing will be necessary to obtain stationarity, then why not simply include the maximum differencing order in the function call? That is, the "I" in ARIMA is the order of differencing prior to fitting an ARMA model, such that if

y = diff(diff(x)) and y is an ARMA(p,q) process,

then

x follows an ARIMA(p,2,q) process.

In `auto.arima()` you specify the differencing with the `d` argument (or `D` if it involves seasons). So, you want something like this (for a maximum of 3 differences):

```
fit <- auto.arima(val.ts, d=3, ...)
```

From this, you can verify that the fitted values will indeed map onto the original data

```
plot(val.ts)
lines(fit, col="blue")
```

Answer (score 4):

The opposite of `diff` is kind of `cumsum`, but you need to know the starting values at each diff.

e.g:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- runif(100)
z <- cumsum(c(x[1], cumsum(c(diff(x)[1], diff(diff(x))))))
all.equal(z, x)
[1] TRUE
```

Share some of your data to make a reproducible example to better help answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the example below containing dummy data, I have double differenced. First, I removed seasonality (lag = 12) and then I removed trend from the differenced data (lag = 1).

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rep(NA,24)
x <- x %>% 
  rnorm(mean = 10, sd = 5) %>% 
  round(.,0) %>% 
  abs()

yy <- diff(x, lag = 12)
z <- diff(yy, lag = 1)
```

Using the script that @jeremycg included above and I include below, how would I remove the double difference? Would I need to add lag specifiers to the two nested diff() commands? If so, which diff() would have the lag = 12 specifier and which would have the lag = 1?

```
zz <- cumsum(c(x[1], cumsum(c(diff(x)[1], diff(diff(x))))))
```